# Server Driven Ajax Framework similar to JqueryMobile

Tags: ajax, web-applications, jquery-mobile

Is there any other Server Driven Ajax Framework similar to Jquery Mobile ( which can fetch a complete page without refresh and update the ui ) for normal Ajax Web Application instead of Mobile Web Application ?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Server Driven'? An important point about jQueryMobile's AJAX navigation is that the server doesn't need to know anything about it. Just make sure your HTML uses the right data-* attributes, and the client does all the rest.

Comment: @ofri Server Driven means , ultimately server decides how the page will look. Even in this case, client is smart, but it is not deciding how each page will look. while as I understand, gmail is kind of client driven where server just provide data and all the decision regarding look and feel are taken by client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing at all stopping you using jQuery Mobile for a 'desktop' web application rather than a mobile web application.  You may need to tweak the css slightly.